# little question about a thing when it comes to dynamically allocate a string, how can I solve?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc, c-strings

(this question is all about theory).

quick doubt, I don't know what to do: I need to do a malloc to store a string of its length plus 1 zero-terminator. Therefore I have to write:
char* str = malloc(length + 1), and in order to avoid buffer overflow/buffer overrun, I've thought about this solution:

```
int sum = length + 1; 
if (sum > char storage limit) {
exit(1); 
} else {
char* str = malloc(length + 1); 
NULL POINTER EXCEPTION CHECK.
}
```

okay, this could work, but I don't know what should I write instead of "char storage size".

knowing that char value range is -128<char<255, and char storage size is 1 byte, but I can't write 8, because 8 doesn't stand for 8 bits; how can I do it?

EDIT: perhaps, I can use sizeof operator this way: sizeof(char). And the code would become:

```
int sum = length + 1; 
if (sum > sizeof(char)) {
exit(1);
} else { /* same way */ }
```

but because this kind of integer types are machine-dependent, their storage size may vary, therefore I think I should write int8_t, because stdint functions have always the same storage size. what do you think?

Comment: How can a buffer overflow occur if you allocated memory char* str = malloc(length + 1),? The question is unclear.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow everytime I have to use malloc, compiler warns me that "it can overflow before being assigned to a wider type". it's not an error, but a "grey squiggle" below the argument of malloc.

Comment: It is strange but neither compiler issues such a warning for me.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow look at the image, look below the argument of malloc

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is, **by definition**, `1` (see [C11 6.5.3.4p4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p4)).

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini Please show a [mcve] that triggers the warning. Did you include `<stdlib.h>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You incorrectly understand the compiler message.

Firstly there is a compilation error

```
if (sum > )
         ^^^
```

and the compiler points to it.

Secondly the message means that instead of the type `int` of the variable `length` you should use the type `size_t`.

This message has nothing common with the buffer overflow. It means that the expression `length + 1` can result in integer overflow.

Pay attention to that `sizeof( char )`, `sizeof( signed char )` and `sizeof( unsigned char )` are always equal to `1`.