# problem when trying to store the longest word in a string into another string?

Tags: c, max, c-strings, strlen, function-definition

This question is mainly based on my past question: to solve this exercise, I needed to ask a standalone question; here's the link: " [little question about a thing when it comes to dynamically allocate a string, how can I solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71113770/little-question-about-a-thing-when-it-comes-to-dynamically-allocate-a-string-ho) ". (I said it, because problems are in the heap).

this is the exercise:

- write a function that find the longest word in a string, and return another string (dynamically allocated in the heap). (word is defined as: sequence of alphanumeric characters without whitespaces).

this is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
char* longest_word(const char* sz) {
    size_t length = 0; 
    for (size_t i = 0; sz[i] != 0; i++) {
        if (isspace(sz[i])) {
            length = 0; 
        }
        else {
            length++; 
        }
    }
    size_t sum = length + 1; 
    char* str = malloc(sum); 
    if (str == NULL) {
        return NULL; 
    }
    size_t stringlength = strlen(sz); 
    size_t sl = stringlength - (sum - 1); 
    for (size_t i = sl; sz[i] != 0; i++) {
        str[i] = sz[i]; 
    }
    str[sum - 1] = 0; 
    return str; 
 
}


int main(void) {
    char sz[] = "widdewdw ededudeide sjfsdhiuodsfhuiodfihuodsfihuodsihuodsihuosdihuquesto"; 
    char* str; 
    str = longest_word(sz); 
    free(str); 
    return 0; 
}
```

the final string is the following: "ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍsjfsdhiuodsfhuiodfihuodsfihuodsi".
this is a good sign, because that means that my thinking process was right (although not entirely).

here's a detailed explanation:

- find the length of the longest string, if the current character is a whitespace start counting from zero again. this works.
- allocate enough space to store each character, plus the zero-terminator. (I've used size_t, because of the accepted answer of the linked question).
- here's the critical part: "sz[i]" is the i-th position in the original string (i.e "sz").   I start counting from sz[i].
- I have copied each character into str[i] until zero-terminator is reached.
  at the end, placed 0 in str[sum-1], (not str[sum], because I've done it and it turned out to be a buffer overflow).

Comment: You should ask yourself: what is the initial value of `i` in the second for loop? Is it always 0? And if not, what do you store in the first bytes of the `str` array?

Comment: @Jabberwocky in the second for loop I start counting from sl, because the longest word starts at sz[sl]

Comment: I suppose you're using Visual Studio. If this is the case, use the debugger. It's worth to invest 20 minutes to learn it's basics, it will quicky pay off. Other debuggers that that of Visual Studio are slighly more complicated, maybe you need an hours or so.

Comment: Read my first comment again closely.

Answer (score 1):

The funtion is incorrect.

This for loop

```
size_t length = 0; 
for (size_t i = 0; sz[i] != 0; i++) {
    if (isspace(sz[i])) {
        length = 0; 
    }
    else {
        length++; 
    }
}
```

does not find the maximum length of words in the string. It returns just the last calculated value of the variable `length`. For example if the string is ended with a space then the value of `length` after the loop will be equal to 0.

And this for loop

```
for (size_t i = sl; sz[i] != 0; i++) {
    str[i] = sz[i]; 
}
```

is trying to copy the tail of the string but not the word with the maximum length.

The function can be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * longest_word( const char *s )
{
    const char *delim = " \t";
    
    size_t max_n = 0;
    const char *max_word = s;
    
    for ( const char *p = s; *p; )
    {
        p += strspn( p, delim );
        
        if ( *p )
        {
            const char *q = p;
            
            p += strcspn( p, delim );
            size_t n = p - q;
            
            if ( max_n < n )
            {
                max_n = n;
                max_word = q;
            }
        }
    }
    
    char *result = malloc( max_n + 1 );
    
    if ( result != NULL )
    {
        result[max_n] = '\0';
        memcpy( result, max_word, max_n );
    }
    
    return result;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "Find the longest word";
    
    char *p = longest_word( s );
    
    if ( p ) puts( p );
    
    free( p );
}
```

The program output is

```
longest
```

Comment: the first for loop is supposed to find the length of the longest word. I've found the maximum length with strlen.

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini With using the function strlen you found the length of the original passed string.